# convert img list to horizontal scroller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image

i have a sets of list of 3 images returned from the server as a result
i would like the user to see only one img for each li and enable him to scroll right and left.

meaning the user will see only two images and will be able to scroll all three all three for each image.

any ideas?

please see the example above:

`<ul>`
   `<li>`
            `<img width="100" height="100" src="http://localhost/TTT/0//1_101.png">` 
            `<img width="100" height="100" src="http://localhost/TTT/0//1_102.png">` 
             `<img width="100" height="100" src="http://localhost/TTT/0//1_103.png">` 
   `</li>`
    `<li>`
            `<img width="100" height="100" src="http://localhost/TTT/0//1_104.png">` 
            `<img width="100" height="100" src="http://localhost/TTT/0//1_105.png">` 
             `<img width="100" height="100" src="http://localhost/TTT/0//1_106.png">` 
   `</li>`
`</ul>`

Answer (score 0):

Shoud you try to set

```
li{display:inline}
```

then set a dimension to

```
#divCongtainer { width:100px; }
```

container, then set

```
#divCongtainer{ width:100px; overflow:auto; }
```

Comment: i want to add right and left button which will scroll right and left , meaning for every li added to the result will have the functionality i mentioned